# How do I go back to a previous line after an ErrorHandler?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry about how basic the question is. Just trying to learn VBA here.

I have the following code

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    YourDoB = InputBox("Enter your date of birth")
ErrorHandler:        ' Error-handling routine.
Select Case Err.Number   ' Evaluate error number.
      Case 13   ' Wrong type'
         MsgBox ("That is not a date!")
End Select
```

I want to make it so if the person introduces an invalid Date of Birth, after the error message the input box appear again asking for DOB until a correct answer has been given. Any idea how to best do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this, using `IsDate` to validate the input.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rawInput As Variant, yourDOB As Date

    Do
        rawInput = InputBox("Enter your date of birth")

        If Not IsDate(rawInput) Then
            MsgBox "That is not a date!"
        Else
            yourDOB = CDate(rawInput)
        End If

    Loop While Not IsDate(rawInput)
End Sub
```